# A component approach instead of Vue

Tags: javascript

I use Electron with NodeJS but this is mainly a javascript question. I got tired of build processes and being dependent of frameworks like Vue so I started my own.

### Setup in `index.html`

```html
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="home"></div>
<script>
var components = {};

// component(name)
var component = (name) => components[name].html();

// Put components into components{}
const componentpath = path.join(__dirname, './snippets2');
  glob.sync(`${componentpath}/**/*.js`).forEach((file) => {
    components[path.parse(file).name] = require(file);
});

// Created hook before anything else
for (const key in components) {
  const component = components[key];
  if (component.hasOwnProperty('created')) {
    component.created();
  }
};

// Place to HTML
document.querySelector('#home').innerHTML = component('body');

// Init components after HTML is placed
for (const key in components) {
  const component = components[key];
  if (component.hasOwnProperty('init')) {
    component.init();
  }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### A component example

```js
module.exports = {
  html() {
    return /*html*/ `
    <div>
      Some HTML ${component('someOtherComponent')}
    </div>
    `;
  },
  created() {
    this.myCustomMethod();
  },
  init() {
    console.log("After HTML is placed on site");
  },
  myCustomMethod() {
    console.log("Custom method, before HTML is placed on site");
  }
};
```

Is it a good approach? Are there any pitfalls with it that you see?

Comment: how do you trigger a re-render ?

Comment: @kemicofaghost So far I don't use a store/state two way data binding. Instead I use a more traditional way. I have a function named update(). It updates an array of values (not in the example) within the scope. Then it runs html() again which uses the new values in the array. I use innerHTML to put it back to the DOM. Not very fancy but so far it has worked well.